I got a connection error when scraping a website using python
Am trying to scrape questions and answers from exammate to get topical questions using the requests library, BeautifulSoup , a regex and then download the images. I got a lot of this code from a previous StackOverflow question.
Error :
Scraping CH1...

Error fetching URL https://www.exam-mate.com/topicalpastpapers?cat=3&sub=29&t\[0\]=54&papers\[0\]=7: ('Connection aborted.', HTTPException("Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://www.exam-mate.com/topicalpastpapers?cat=3&sub=29&t[0]=54&papers[0]=7'."))

Scraping CH2...

Error fetching URL https://www.exam-mate.com/topicalpastpapers?cat=3&sub=29&t\[0\]=55&papers\[0\]=7: ('Connection aborted.', HTTPException("Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://www.exam-mate.com/topicalpastpapers?cat=3&sub=29&t[0]=55&papers[0]=7'."))

Scraping completed!

Full code :
import re
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint

# Headers to mimic a browser request
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
}

# Define your topics and URLs
topic_urls = {
    "CH1": "https://www.exam-mate.com/topicalpastpapers?cat=3&sub=29&t[0]=54&papers[0]=7",
    "CH2": "https://www.exam-mate.com/topicalpastpapers?cat=3&sub=29&t[0]=55&papers[0]=7",
    # Add more topics as needed
}

# Base URL
BASE_URL = "https://www.exam-mate.com"

# Retry mechanism for downloading images
def download_image(image_url, save_path, retries=3):
    for attempt in range(retries):
        try:
            response = requests.get(image_url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                with open(save_path, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(response.content)
                print(f"Downloaded: {save_path}")
                return
            else:
                print(f"Failed to download {image_url}: Status {response.status_code}")
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error on attempt {attempt + 1} for {image_url}: {e}")
        sleep(randint(1, 3))  # Random delay between retries
    print(f"Failed to download after {retries} attempts: {image_url}")

# Scrape each topic
for topic, url in topic_urls.items():
    print(f"Scraping {topic}...")

    # Create topic-specific folders
    os.makedirs(f"images/{topic}/questions", exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(f"images/{topic}/answers", exist_ok=True)

    try:
        # Get the webpage
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching URL {url}: {e}")
        continue

    # Extract image links
    for idx, tag in enumerate(soup.select("td:nth-of-type(1) a")):
        try:
            # Extract the image link
            question_link = re.search(r"/questions.*\.png", tag["onclick"]).group()
            full_url = BASE_URL + question_link

            # Save to appropriate folder (even index: questions, odd index: answers)
            if idx % 2 == 0:  # Even index: questions
                save_path = f"images/{topic}/questions/question_{idx // 2 + 1}.png"
            else:  # Odd index: answers
                save_path = f"images/{topic}/answers/answer_{idx // 2 + 1}.png"

            # Download the image
            download_image(full_url, save_path)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing tag: {tag}, {e}")

print("Scraping completed!")

I'm not sure what to do. Also, incase its worth mentioning, I used some ChatGPT and ran on its console. I know its not the best idea.
I want to download the questions and answers as PNG images into separate folders as questions and answers for each topic.

Probably the usual problem with web-scraping questions: the site is defending against automated scraping and is blocking you.

this is not a regular exception you have here, if you're using some jupyter flavor please add it to your tags

You probably ought to use selenium for this because the site is heavily reliant on Javascript.
You can use requests to acquire the images.
For improved performance you could consider multithreading the download process.
It then becomes simply:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

topic_urls = {
    "CH1": "https://www.exam-mate.com/topicalpastpapers?cat=3&sub=29&t[0]=54&papers[0]=7",
    "CH2": "https://www.exam-mate.com/topicalpastpapers?cat=3&sub=29&t[0]=55&papers[0]=7",
    # Add more topics as needed
}

OPTIONS = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
OPTIONS.add_argument("--headless=true")

CSS_Q = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#question-image-box-1 img.img-fluid"
CSS_A = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#answer-image-box-1 img.img-fluid"
EC_ALL = EC.presence_of_all_elements_located

def download(url: str | None, target: Path) -> None:
    if url:
        target.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        with requests.get(url, stream=True) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            file = target / url.split("/")[-1]
            with file.open("wb") as image_file:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(4096):
                    image_file.write(chunk)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with webdriver.Chrome(OPTIONS) as driver:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            for topic, url in topic_urls.items():
                driver.get(url)
                image, *_ = wait.until(EC_ALL(CSS_Q))
                qtarget = Path(f"images/{topic}/questions")
                executor.submit(download, image.get_attribute("src"), qtarget)
                image, *_ = wait.until(EC_ALL(CSS_A))
                atarget = Path(f"images/{topic}/answers")
                executor.submit(download, image.get_attribute("src"), atarget)

